# Base R: add points() in a loop defined by group

Tags: r, loops, plot, dataframe, points

I am looking for a way to generate different plots in base R with adding points and lines manually to the plot.

```
xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2"), X_START_YEAR=c(1984,1986,1899,1903), Y_START_VALUE=c(75,25,-90,-8),X_END_YEAR=c(1986,1994,1909,1924),Y_END_VALUE=c(20,50,-15,-70))
xy
      NAME          X_START_YEAR    Y_START_VALUE   X_END_YEAR   Y_END_VALUE
    1 NAME1         1984            75              1986          20
    2 NAME1         1986            25              1994          50
    3 NAME2         1899           -90              1909         -15
    4 NAME2         1903            -8              1924         -70
```

Is it possible to add `points()` to a plot with the values from the first row (STARTING POINT `X_START_YEAR/Y_START VALUE` to END POINT: `X_END_YEAR/Y_END_VALUE`) and then plot again in the same plot in the same scheme the values for the second row.

After this plot has been generated a new group defined by `NAME` starts and a new plot should be generated for rows 3 and 4 in the same scheme as above.

Unlike in this sample data, I have about 40000 rows and 1300 groups in the end and I am looking for a way to correctly plot this data in base R. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you want diffrent color for each row in the same group?

Comment: no. but two plots should result in the end out of this sample data, a plot for each group defined by NAME here (so row 1 and 2 form a group and row 3 and 4 another group)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your data by name , and plot each group like this :

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2)))   ## don't use layout in your case
for (dat in split(xy,xy$NAME)){
  xx = unlist(dat[,grep('X_',colnames(dat))])
  yy = unlist(dat[,grep('Y_',colnames(dat))])
  plot(xx,yy,main=unique(dat[,1]),pch=20)
  dat <- dat[,-1]
  segments(dat[,1],dat[,2],dat[,3],dat[,4])
}
```

[image]

This will result in a plot for each group. Of course if you save the result to other thing than the console , you should define the device where to plot before.

Comment: thank you. is there also a way to do this with points() so that I can connect start and end point by lines by specifying type=l for example?

Comment: @redshoe you can see my edit. I think I get your point maybe.